# How to fix Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm having trouble connecting or logging in to my SQL Server database. I had a previous working instance before, but I forgot the password and decided to just reinstall the whole thing since I don't have any data to lose. I realized that was a bad idea but now, each time I attempt to log in to my SQL Server, I get the following error message:

[image]

I tried to search for an answer, but it seems nothing is working. Here is what I tried so far:

1. Enabling the `Named Pipes` from the `SQL Server Configuration Manager` under the `SQL Server Network Configuration` tree item
2. I tried restarting the `SQL Server` item from the list of services in the `Services` application
3. I tried restarting everything in the `SQL Server Configuration Manager` that is related to my database or at least have my instance's name on it

There are other things that I tried which I fail to remember. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try to create a new instance of SQL server user OR
If it is an option for you then try to uninstall every SQL Server-related program from your PC then try to re-install the SQL server, then create the new instance of server user.

Comment: I tried this for a couple of times and also deleted the remaining folders from the `Program Files` forlders (both of them), but for some reason, I keep encountering this error. Also, the previous instance that I deleted before, is still suggested as an instance whenever I open the management studio

Comment: Just some advice for next time: don't use login/password, use windows authentication. At this stage (after reinstalls, deleting folders etc.) who knows what state your install is. I'd hazard a guess that there is no running SQL Server service at all. Also when you reinstalled SQL Server you probably deleted your data files. Anyway, first thing to do is ensure the SQL Server starts OK in services.

Comment: Thank you for the advice but I already tried that when I first searched for a solution for this. Restarting, stopping and starting the services were the first few solutions I found online but apparently, its still not working. Also, I tried both the username and password login as well as the windows authentication but both didn't work

Comment: Is it a named instance or default instance? Are you using an instance name to connect or just the hostname/IP address?

Comment: I tried to connect in the default instance at first and when that didn't worked, I tried to create a named instance but I wasn't able to access that as well